# Plotting finite series with Bessel functions and Bessel zero's

Tags: plotting, special-functions, summation, fourier-analysis

I would like to plot the Nth partial sum of the Fourier series of $f(x) = 1$ with the 0th order Bessel function as the eigenfunctions. This sum corresponds to:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2 J_0(x \lambda_{0n})}{\lambda_{0n} J_1(\lambda_{0n})}$$

Where $\lambda_{0n}$ is the nth zero of the 0th order Bessel function. I would like to plot this for $N = 5, 10$.

My attempt:

```
An[n_] := 2/(BesselJZero[0, n] BesselJ[1, BesselJZero[0, n]])

BesselFourier[x_, N_] := Sum[A_n[n] BesselJ[0, BesselJZero[0, n] x], {n, N}]

Plot[BesselFourier[x, 5], {x, 0, 1}]
```

However, when I execute this, I get a blank plot. I have also tried to surround the sum in Evaluate[], but got the same result. Any advice?

Comment: The blank comes from your use of `A_n[n]` there in the code.

Comment: @Nasser Yupp, that fixed it. Can we bring 'facepalm' back now?

Answer (score 1):

Few corrections. Do not use `N` as variable. Call was wrong for `An`

```
An[n_]:=2/(BesselJZero[0,n] BesselJ[1,BesselJZero[0,n]]);
BesselFourier[x_,max_]:=Sum[An[n] BesselJ[0,BesselJZero[0,n] x],{n,max}];
Plot[BesselFourier[x,2],{x,0,1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is little slow for more terms, but this could be optimized if needed. (I think the slowness comes from `BesselJZero` but not sure now)

```
 Plot[BesselFourier[x,5],{x,0,1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]